# Multiple columns on x-axis stacked bar charts

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm beginner in R programming, exploring ggplot. I'm trying to plot stacked bar chart to show 3 years quarterly revenue for multiple countries.
I'm using data from https://www.ibm.com/communities/analytics/watson-analytics-blog/sales-products-sample-data/

```
mydata <- read.csv("~/Downloads/WA_Sales_Products_2012-14.csv") 
library(dplyr)
qtrSales <- mydata %>%
group_by(mydata$Retailer.country, mydata$Year, mydata$Quarter) %>%
summarize(Rev=sum(Revenue)) %>%

qtrSales <- data.frame(qtrSales)
colnames(qtrSales) <- c("Country", "Year", "Qtr", "Revenue")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(y=qtrSales$Revenue, x = qtrSales$Year, 
fill=qtrSales$Qtr), data=qtrSales, stat="identity")
```

above ggplot is giving me [image]
what I want is to have 3 bars for each year grouped together for each country. Can anyone advise how to achieve it?

Comment: Do you need to group by quarters too? There are 21 countries and stacked geom_bar will look terrible, I would suggest using something else

Comment: you could add year in a facet_wrap, in that way you'd be able to see quarter growth.  It won't be very readable if you have grouped bars, but if you insist, look into position = "dodge"

Comment: Thank you for reverting. Pardon my lack of knowledge, what else would you suggest? I guess you're right about it looking messy with all 21 countries. If I change scenario, to limit 5 or 10 countries, can it be done based on my original requirement?

Comment: @ssjsk do you need to present quarter information too?

Comment: @PoGibas yes I'm trying to have Quarters for each year to be stacked in bars for each year

Comment: @User632716 thanks, I'll try to explore that meanwhile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I put `Quarter` instead of `Year` on x-axis, otherwise you would need to use facets.

```
colnames(mydata)[1] <- "Country"
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydata, aes(Quarter, Revenue, fill = Country)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = unique(mydata$Quarter)) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: @ssjsk Is there something else you want to display/adjust?

Comment: awesome, thank you for this one, I'll explore more using facet in order to learn more :-) appreciate your quick response.

Comment: @ssjsk happy to help :-)